# how to cache asyncio coroutines

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I am using [aiohttp](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.org) to make a simple HTTP request in python 3.4 like this:

```
response = yield from aiohttp.get(url)
```

The application requests the same URL over and over again so naturally I wanted to cache it. My first attempt was something like this:

```
@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=128)
def cached_request(url):
    return aiohttp.get(url)
```

The first call to `cached_request` works fine, but in later calls I end up with `None` instead of the response object.

I am rather new to asyncio so I tried a lot of combinations of the `asyncio.coroutine` decorator, `yield from` and some other things, but none seemed to work.

So how does caching coroutines work?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by caching a coroutine? e.g. Save it as a variable so that you can call it repeatedly? Save the result, till the result is replaced on a later execution? Or have the same coroutine repeat at a later time?

Comment: @shongololo I want to cache the result of the coroutine.

Comment: I am not familiar with functools.lru_cache() but if you simply want to return updated results, then is there any reason  you don't just save the updated results to a variable? Nevertheless, when using an asynchronous method (such as `aiohttp.get()`) you have to drive it with something. So cached_request has to be enclosed with `@asyncio.coroutine`; it has to be called using`yield from`; and the return statement should be framed along the lines of `return (yield from aiohttp.get(url))`

Answer (score 12):

Maybe a bit late, but I've started a new package that may help: https://github.com/argaen/aiocache. Contributions/comments are always welcome.

An example:

```
import asyncio

from collections import namedtuple

from aiocache import cached
from aiocache.serializers import PickleSerializer

Result = namedtuple('Result', "content, status")


@cached(ttl=10, serializer=PickleSerializer())
async def async_main():
    print("First ASYNC non cached call...")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return Result("content", 200)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    print(loop.run_until_complete(async_main()))
    print(loop.run_until_complete(async_main()))
    print(loop.run_until_complete(async_main()))
    print(loop.run_until_complete(async_main()))
```

Note that as an extra, it can cache any python object into redis using Pickle serialization. In case you just want to work with memory, you can use the `SimpleMemoryCache` backend :).

Answer (score 11):

An popular async version of `lru_cache` exist here: [async_lru](https://pypi.org/project/async_lru/)

Answer (score 9):

To use `functools.lru_cache` with coroutines, the following code works.

```
class Cacheable:
    def __init__(self, co):
        self.co = co
        self.done = False
        self.result = None
        self.lock = asyncio.Lock()

    def __await__(self):
        with (yield from self.lock):
            if self.done:
                return self.result
            self.result = yield from self.co.__await__()
            self.done = True
            return self.result

def cacheable(f):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        r = f(*args, **kwargs)
        return Cacheable(r)
    return wrapped


@functools.lru_cache()
@cacheable
async def foo():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            return await resp.text()
```

The following is thread safe

```
class ThreadSafeCacheable:
    def __init__(self, co):
        self.co = co
        self.done = False
        self.result = None
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    def __await__(self):
        while True:
            if self.done:
                return self.result
            if self.lock.acquire(blocking=False):
                self.result = yield from self.co.__await__()
                self.done = True
                return self.result
            else:
                yield from asyncio.sleep(0.005)
```

Comment: Thanks! One case where it does not work though: when the decorated coroutine raises an exception. In that case `self.done` is not set to True and the next call raises `RuntimeError: cannot reuse already awaited coroutine`. In my case I could record the exception and re-raise it, but others might want to re-run the coro (and I don't know if it's possible).

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a simple cache decorator myself:

```
def async_cache(maxsize=128):
    cache = {}

    def decorator(fn):
        def wrapper(*args):                                                         
            key = ':'.join(args)

            if key not in cache:
                if len(cache) >= maxsize:
                    del cache[cache.keys().next()]

                cache[key] = yield from fn(*args)

            return cache[key]

        return wrapper

    return decorator


@async_cache()
@asyncio.coroutine
def expensive_io():
    ....
```

This kind-of-works. But many aspects can probably be improved. For example: If the cached function is called a second time before the first call returns, it will execute a second time.

Comment: Suggestion: use an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to implement `lru` behaviour, i.e. use `OrderedDict.move_to_end` on every key called, and then `OrderedDict.popitem` when the cache is full.

Comment: You can use a Semaphore to limit it to one execution.

Comment: This is a bit dangerous because it relies on the string representation of the arguments. It would be best to stick to hashable objects like the original lru_cache.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I think it's most easily done, using the built-in `lru_cache` and futures:

```py
import asyncio
import functools

# parameterless decorator
def async_lru_cache_decorator(async_function):
    @functools.lru_cache
    def cached_async_function(*args, **kwargs):
        coroutine = async_function(*args, **kwargs)
        return asyncio.ensure_future(coroutine)
    return cached_async_function

# decorator with options
def async_lru_cache(*lru_cache_args, **lru_cache_kwargs):
    def async_lru_cache_decorator(async_function):
        @functools.lru_cache(*lru_cache_args, **lru_cache_kwargs)
        def cached_async_function(*args, **kwargs):
            coroutine = async_function(*args, **kwargs)
            return asyncio.ensure_future(coroutine)
        return cached_async_function
    return async_lru_cache_decorator

@async_lru_cache(maxsize=128)
async def your_async_function(...): ...
```

This is basically taking your original function and wrapping it so I can store the `Coroutine` it returns and convert it into a `Future`. This way, this can be treated as a regular function and you can `lru_cache`-it as you would usually do it.

Why is wrapping it in a Future necessary? Python coroutines are low level constructs and you can't `await` one more than once (You would get `RuntimeError: cannot reuse already awaited coroutine`). Futures, on the other hand, are handy and can be awaited consecutively and will return the same result.

One caveat is that caching a `Future` will also cache when the original functions raised an `Error`. The original `lru_cache` does not cache interrupted executions, so watch out for this edge case using the solution above.

Further tweaking can be done to merge both the parameter-less and the parameterized decorators, like the original `lru_cache` which supports both usages.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not that familiar with aiohttp so I'm not sure of exactly what is happening that would cause Nones to be returned, but the lru_cache decorator will not work with async functions.

I use a decorator which does essentially the same thing; note that it is different to tobib's decorator above in that it will always return a future or a task, rather than the value:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from functools import _make_key, wraps

def future_lru_cache(maxsize=128):
    # support use as decorator without calling, for this case maxsize will
    # not be an int
    try:
        real_max_size = int(maxsize)
    except ValueError:
        real_max_size = 128

    cache = OrderedDict()

    async def run_and_cache(func, args, kwargs):
        """Run func with the specified arguments and store the result
        in cache."""
        result = await func(*args, **kwargs)
        cache[_make_key(args, kwargs, False)] = result
        if len(cache) > real_max_size:
            cache.popitem(False)
        return result

    def wrapper(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
            key = _make_key(args, kwargs, False)
            if key in cache:
                # Some protection against duplicating calls already in
                # progress: when starting the call cache the future, and if
                # the same thing is requested again return that future.
                if isinstance(cache[key], asyncio.Future):
                    return cache[key]
                else:
                    f = asyncio.Future()
                    f.set_result(cache[key])
                    return f
            else:
                task = asyncio.Task(run_and_cache(func, args, kwargs))
                cache[key] = task
                return task
        return decorator

    if callable(maxsize):
        return wrapper(maxsize)
    else:
        return wrapper
```

I used _make_key from functools as lru_cache does, I guess it's supposed to be private so probably better to copy it over.

Answer (score 2):

Try [async-cache :pypi](https://pypi.org/project/async-cache/) [async-cache :github](https://github.com/iamsinghrajat/async-cache) for caching async functions in python.

It also supports function which have parameters of *`user defined`* or *`object type`* or *`unhashable`* type which is not supported in either *`functools.lru_cache`* or *`async_lru`* .

**Usage:**

```
pip install async-cache
```

```
from cache import AsyncLRU

@AsyncLRU(maxsize=128)
async def func(*args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

Comment: Worked for me best in Feb 2022

Answer (score 1):

Another variant of lru decorator, which caches not yet finished coroutines, very useful with parallel requests to the same key:

```
import asyncio
from collections import OrderedDict
from functools import _make_key, wraps

def async_cache(maxsize=128, event_loop=None):
    cache = OrderedDict()
    if event_loop is None:
        event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    awaiting = dict()

    async def run_and_cache(func, args, kwargs):
        """await func with the specified arguments and store the result
        in cache."""
        result = await func(*args, **kwargs)
        key = _make_key(args, kwargs, False)
        cache[key] = result
        if len(cache) > maxsize:
            cache.popitem(False)
        cache.move_to_end(key)
        return result

    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            key = _make_key(args, kwargs, False)
            if key in cache:
                return cache[key]
            if key in awaiting:
                task = awaiting[key]
                return await asyncio.wait_for(task, timeout=None, loop=event_loop)
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(run_and_cache(func, args, kwargs), loop=event_loop)
            awaiting[key] = task
            result = await asyncio.wait_for(task, timeout=None, loop=event_loop)
            del awaiting[key]
            return result
        return wrapper

    return decorator


async def test_async_cache(event_loop):
    counter = 0
    n, m = 10, 3

    @async_cache(maxsize=n, event_loop=event_loop)
    async def cached_function(x):
        nonlocal counter
        await asyncio.sleep(0)  # making event loop switch to other coroutine
        counter += 1
        return x

    tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(cached_function(x), loop=event_loop)
             for x in list(range(n)) * m]
    done, pending = await asyncio.wait(tasks, loop=event_loop, timeout=1)
    assert len(done) == n * m
    assert counter == n

event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
task = asyncio.ensure_future(test_async_cache(event_loop))
event_loop.run_until_complete(task)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the simplest way is to use [aiohttp_cache](https://github.com/cr0hn/aiohttp-cache) ([documentation](https://aiohttp-cache.readthedocs.org/))

```
pip install aiohttp-cache
```

And use it in code:

```
from aiohttp_cache import cache, setup_cache

@cache()  # <-- DECORATED FUNCTION
async def example_1(request):
    return web.Response(text="Example")


app = web.Application()

app.router.add_route('GET', "/", example_1)

setup_cache(app)  # <-- INITIALIZED aiohttp-cache

web.run_app(app, host="127.0.0.1")
```

Comment: Do you need additional caching on the client too?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple package named `asyncio-cache` -  https://github.com/matan1008/asyncio-cache.

I tried to keep the code as close as possible to the original python implementation and as simple as possible.

For example:

```py
from asyncio_cache import lru_cache
import aiohttp

@lru_cache(maxsize=128)
async def cached_get(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            return await resp.text()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working with FastAPI. The thing is, it executes the normal `def` dependencies inside another thread. So unless it's not a blocking call, it could be better to use an `async def` dependency.

With that in mind, I also needed to cache the value of this `async def` dependency. So I ended up writing my own which is simple and works:

```py
import asyncio
from functools import wraps


def async_cache(async_fn):
    """Async version of functools.lru_cache"""
    lock = asyncio.Lock()
    cache = {}

    @wraps(async_fn)
    async def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        cache_key = (args, tuple(kwargs.items()))
        if cache_key in cache:
            return cache[cache_key]

        async with lock:
            if cache_key not in cache:
                cache[cache_key] = await async_fn(*args, **kwargs)
        return cache[cache_key]
    return inner


@async_cache
async def square(n, **extras):
    print("inside coroutine")
    await asyncio.sleep(n)
    return n * n


async def main():
    print(await asyncio.gather(*[square(3, foo="bar") for _ in range(4)]))
    print("-----------------------------------")
    print(await asyncio.gather(*[square(3, foo="bar") for _ in range(4)]))


asyncio.run(main())
```

The `lock` object is optional, In my actual code, I only wanted to have one instance from the same parameters so I first grabbed the lock object.